# ADO.NET DataRelation

Tags: c#, ado.net, datarelation

If I create a relation between 2 DataTable in my C# code and then update my DataAdapter + acceptChanged on my DataSet, will this Relation be repercuted on the server or is it only a client based relation which is effective only within the application?

Thanks,

KiTe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship is made within your dataset, the database will not be modified.